# Show that $\lbrace (q,0) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace $ is a closed subset of the Moore Plane

Tags: general-topology, moore-plane

Let $\Gamma$ be the [Moore Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane), I have to show that the set  $\lbrace (q,0) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace $ is closed.

I have tried to prove it by trying to find a neigbourhood of every point in the complimentary, but these neigbourhoods aren't contained in the complimentary, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, I don't know how to start to prove it then.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: For a point $(x,y)$ outside your set, distinguish two cases: (1) $y>0$; (2) $y=0, x\not\in\mathbb Q$. What is the neighbourhood of the points in those two cases which does not intersect your set? In fact, $\mathbb Q$ is a red herring - any subset of the line $y=0$ will be closed by the same argument.

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3932178/4280) might help...