# Trouble understanding why Moore's Plane is not normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, moore-plane

This question was already asked here([Show that the Moore plane is not normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528435/show-that-the-moore-plane-is-not-normal))  but I couldn't understand that answer and also I have another question.

On [page 13](https://books.google.com/books?id=hl_0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13) of Dolciani Expository text in Topology by S.G Krantz author gives an outline why Moore's plane is not normal. But I am unable to deduce it.

Adding image
Firstly, Author gives two sets $A= \{(x,0)\in P \mid x\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $B=\{(x,0)\in P\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\}$, here $P$ is the Moore plane.

> Author tells that both of these sets are closed. In my opinion Closure of both $A$, $B$ should be set $\{(x,0)\in P\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Then it it clear that they are disjoint sets.

> But can you please tell how to prove that they cannot be seperated by open sets?

I can see it intutively but I am afraid that I am wrong as my intution was wrong in question 1 asked above which was very similar.

I am asking for your help as I am bad in topology as course was marred by a bad instructor and wasn't aware of existence of MSE network then.

Comment: $E=\Bbb R\times \{0\}$ is a closed discrete subspace of $P.$ That is, $E$ is a closed subset of $P,$ and the subspace topology on $E$ (as a subspace of $P$) is discrete. If $X$ is any space and if $Y$ is a closed discrete subspace of $X$ then any $Z\subset Y$ is also a closed discrete subspace of $X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $L:=\{(x,0): x \in \Bbb R\}$ is discrete in its subspace topology with resp. to the Moore plane. This holds as for a basic subset of $(x,0)$, which is $\{(x,0)\}$ unioned with a *tangent* ball inside the upper half plane $P :=\{(x,r):x \in \Bbb R, r>0\}$ only intersects $L$ in $\{(x,0)\}$, making it an isolated point in the subspace topology on $L$.

Also, $L$ is closed in the Moore plane (its complement is $P$ which is open by definition of the topology on the Moore plane), so **all** subsets of $L$ are closed in $L$ (as $L$ is discrete) and so also closed in the Moore plane ("closed in closed is closed") as $L$ is closed.

The fact that we use these two sets specifically has other reasons that will become clear later in the proof.

I personally think that the Jones' lemma proof (see my answer to the linked question in your first line) is the nicer way to go with the proof.

Comment: Can you please help me in this question in topology also. This has been unanswered since long :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3931704/unable-to-understand-why-this-set-is-totally-disconnected-s-g-krantz-pg-30

Comment: @Avenger that problem was ill-defined (wrong definition of the space), hence the absence of an answer.