# Unable to understand why this set is totally disconnected( S. G Krantz pg 30)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

While learning Topology from S. G Krantz I have a question in proof of a set contructed with the help of Cantor Set.

[image]

Question is in last line of image.

> I am unable to understand why K/{p} will be totally disconnected.

Why should K/{p} doesn't any connected component which is not singleton?

I see no reason.

Comment: Any connected subset has to lie within one of the lines $L_x$ (some line through $p$ would form a separation otherwise). But each $L_x^*/\{p\}$ is totally disconnected.  It is not at all plain to me that this space is connected.

Comment: I do not think the $L_x^*$ are defined correctly. It should be (if this is "Cantor's Teepee"): if $x\in Q$, then $L_x^*$ is the set of all points in $L_x$ with rational second coordinate. If $x\in P$, then $L_x^*$ is the set of all points in $L_x$ with irrational second coordinate.